# JSoup.clean() is not preserving relative URLs

Tags: html-parsing, jsoup

I have tried:

```
Whitelist.relaxed();
Whitelist.relaxed().preserveRelativeLinks(true);
Whitelist.relaxed().addProtocols("a","href","#","/","http","https","mailto","ftp");
Whitelist.relaxed().addProtocols("a","href","#","/","http","https","mailto","ftp").preserveRelativeLinks(true);
```

None of them work: When I try to clean a relative url, like `<a href="/test.xhtml">test</a>` I get the `href` attribute removed (`<a>test</a>`).

I am using JSoup 1.8.2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem most likely stems from the call of the clean method. If you give the base URI all should work as expected:

```
String html = ""
        + "<a href=\"/test.xhtml\">test</a>"
        + "<invalid>stuff</invalid>"
        + "<h2>header1</h2>";
String cleaned = Jsoup.clean(html, "http://base.uri", Whitelist.relaxed().preserveRelativeLinks(true));
System.out.println(cleaned);
```

The above works and keeps the relative links. With `String cleaned = Jsoup.clean(html, Whitelist.relaxed().preserveRelativeLinks(true))` however the link is deleted.

Note the [documentation of Whitelist.preserveRelativeLinks(true)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html#preserveRelativeLinks-boolean-):

> Note that when handling relative links, the input document must have
>   an appropriate base URI set when parsing, so that the link's protocol
>   can be confirmed. Regardless of the setting of the preserve relative
>   links option, the link must be resolvable against the base URI to an
>   allowed protocol; otherwise the attribute will be removed.