# Jsoup is removing the href attribute with a placeholder value

Tags: jsoup

I am using `jsoup` to clean some html. 
 I am using `Whitelist.relaxed()` to clean. This works well for the most part and I would like to continue to use it.

Problem is that I have a place holder `href` value that the clean is removing.

For example, `<a href="{placeholder}">text</a>`. This is changed to `<a>text</a>`. Is there a way to preserve the `href attribute` with my `place holder` value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [addAttributes](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html#addAttributes-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) whitelist option?

Comment: I have. I have created the following whitelist:   
  
  private static final Whitelist WHITELIST = Whitelist.relaxed().preserveRelativeLinks(true)
      .addTags("span")
      .addTags("hr")
      .addAttributes(":all", "style")
      .addAttributes(":all", "id")
      .addAttributes(":all", "target")
      .addProtocols("a", "href", "{");
I have played around with it a bit and no luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSoup.clean() is not preserving relative URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563027/jsoup-clean-is-not-preserving-relative-urls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you do not give a valid base URI to the `clean` method. If you do that, then you can keep the `href`s. If you also specify [`preserveRelativeLinks(true)`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html#preserveRelativeLinks-boolean-) with the Whitelist, the links can be relative as well.

So when cleaning do something like this:

```
String html = "<a href=\"{placeholder}\">text</a>";
String cleaned = Jsoup.clean(html, 
                             "http://base.uri",
                             Whitelist.relaxed().preserveRelativeLinks(true));
System.out.println(cleaned);
```

This will result in the following output:

```
<a href="{placeholder}">text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only href attribute, you can use "preserveRelativeLinks(true)" . But you have already target = "_blank" or different attributes, method see all this attributes one url. So I preferred WhiteList's "addAttributes(String tag, String... attributes)" [WhiteList addAttributes](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html#addAttributes-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-)

Code like this :

```
WhiteList whiteList = WhiteList.none();
whitelist.addAttributes("a","href","target");
whitelist.addAttributes("img","src");

String cleanText = Jsoup.clean(htmlText, whitelist);
```